# KDB + query - Implement Not like

Tags: kdb

I have to use not like operation  in KDB + query but do not know how exactly to use it.
I am able to use like operator i.e.
http://kdbserver:8001/?select from orderDetails where symbol like "X*"
this query successfully gives the results.

How to use/implement not like for same query ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

select from orderDetails where not symbol like "X*"

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the orders which are not like any of the patterns e.g. selecting the orders which are neither `X*` nor `*Z`

```
select from orderDetails where not any symbol like/:("X*";"*Z")
```

Answer (score 0):

In kdb,
`select col1, col2 from tabel where cond`, cond should be a boolean list. [`like`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/like/) return a boolean list and `not` can flip a boolean list